# Куда сохранять файлы бота на Heroku?

Tags: node.js, heroku

Есть телеграм бот на Node js расположенный на Heroku и ему надо хранить некоторые файлы. Как это реализовать?

Comment: я не знаю, что именно нужно хранить и что за бот, но в этой самой Heroku есть возможность подключить БД. Если мне что-то нужно хранить, то я использую именно БД

Comment: А где расположена эта функция?

Comment: сначала добавляете свое приложение, потом в меню выбираете Data и там можно создать инстанс БД на базе Postgres , беслатно до 10000 записей. можно и MySQL, но там уже надо поиграться.

Comment: https://habr.com/sandbox/69602/ Вот должно помочь, подробная инструкция, сам сейчас разбираюсь тоже ;)